# I need javascript to automatically prefix+suffix as it populates a field? I want it to be surrounded with apostrophes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

div with-altfield is a multidatepicker. Upon selection of a date it populates the altfield input. In format, mm/dd/yy,mm/dd/yy,.. I want it to actually populate the input with apostrophes surrounding the date selected. Like, 'mm/dd/yy','mm/dd/yy',... this is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

$(function() {
    $('#with-altField').multiDatesPicker({
        altField: '#altField',

    });;
});

</script>

</head>
<body>                          
 <div id="with-altField"></div>
 <input type="text" id="altField">
</body>
```

Please help!
Thank you
Si

Comment: `    });;` two semicolons, typo?

Comment: @LightStyle Still valid javascript, no? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [`dateFormat`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat) option. The syntax is explained [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate).

```
$('#with-altField').multiDatesPicker({
    altField: '#altField',
    dateFormat: "''mm/dd/yy''"
});
```

Comment: That has added the apostrophes!... but has lost the multidatepicker selection ability it only selects one date? how can this be fixed? Thank you Jon